# Is there a string length limit for parsing JSON using org.json.me

Tags: json, blackberry

I am using org.json.me (*https://github.com/upictec/org.json.me*) on Blackberry OS 5.0.

I am getting the following the error when parsing a JSON message coming from a server.

```
JSONException: Expected a ',' or '}' at character 16201...
```

**My question:  Is there a string length limit for parsing when using this library?**

*Additional Info*:
The API I am testing allows the client to provide a search query and the maximum number records to return.  When I make a call, asking for 100 records, I get this error.  This response has 28542 characters.
When I ask for 50 records, it works OK - no errors.  This response has 14195 characters.

**Is this a limit with the json classes or is my code buggy somewhere?**

Comment: from what the error shows you probably have an error in the json as it fails to parse it. are you using commas or pharantesses unescaped in your json string?

Comment: use http://jsonlint.com/ and paste your json there, and see if it validates it properly

Comment: Thanks @rfsk2010: jsonlint reports that it is valid (i.e. the 100 records response).  bogdam, I am not using any commas or parens.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're not getting all the data from the server. There are strict size limits when receiving data over mobile transports. Try switching to Wi-Fi to see if that makes any difference.

Comment: I am getting the error on the 9900 simualtor running OS7.  It may not be a transport limitation, but I will take a further look.  Thanks.

Comment: I am facing same problem ..can any body getsolution